# css3 how to trigger an event when a transition is half-way done?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I think everything is in the title.
I add a class with javascript which basically does :

```
.rotation {
   transform:rotateY(180deg);
   transition-timing-function: linear;
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

I need to know when the transition has reached 90 deg. Those values are for the example. The problem is, if I repeat 2 transformations of 90degs, I get a short lag in the middle, not under Chrome but under Microsoft Edge and Firefox.

Does someone has the solution, either to have an event triggered halfway or to avoid this lag when repeating a transition?

Thanks!

Comment: you could use animations and then control what happens within the animation with @keyframes

Comment: do you have events triggered when reaching certain keyframes? Because the point is to update something in the page when the animation or transition is halfway done.

Comment: look at this demo: http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/GrbXrQ - here I change the background color half way through the animation

Comment: In need to have event triggered because I have computations to do in javascript. But I see "animationiteration" could do the trick for subiterations defined by keyframes... I will check, thanks!

Comment: @Joel: `animationiteration` will fire after each iteration but it won't fire at 50% of an iteration which is what you seem to be wanting based on the question. If you want to do JS operations at a specified point, I think, you'd have to use a timer which is fired on `animationstart` and then use half of `animation-duration` as the time.

Comment: @Harry, thanks. Actually I could split my animation into 2 animations chained and use animation-iteration-count to get what I want. I tested it, I am nearly there:  I flip a card and present 2 photos, and change the photo when it is on the hidden side, this is why it needs to be very accurate in the timing. I will test your method as well.

Comment: Got you now @Joel. Not a bad option if you could split your thing into two equal parts (since your timing function is linear that won't cause any unexpected problems either). The method suggested by vals is also worth having a look at (in case your current approach runs into any problems).

Comment: Yes definitely, thanks a lot to the both of you.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the easiest way to achieve what you want is setting an additional transition on some property that isn't visible.

I have sometimes used z-index, but you can choose another one. Then:

```
div {
    transition: transform 1s linear, z-index 0.5s linear;
    z-index: 1;
}
.rotation {
    z-index: 2;
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

You will get 2 events, the first one at 0.5s

Comment: Thanks. I also did some tests on my end, I use keyframes and animation with animation-iteration-count set to a certain value. The event animationiteration is triggered for each iteration after the first, so it seems it is also a suitable solution: I check if we are in the middle, elapsedTime is passed as an argument and it is easy to check where we are in the process.